# Does ReactJS parse object literals into strings?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am walking through the ReactJS tutorial right now, mulling over the section 'Thinking In React', and in particular an aspect of the code really bothers me:

```
class ProductRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
      this.props.product.name :
      <span style={{color: 'red', background: 'green'}}>     // this line
        {this.props.product.name}
      </span>;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

For the rest of the code, see: http://codepen.io/lacker/pen/vXpAgj

... at line 11, style is assigned {color: 'red'}. In my head, this shouldn't work, because it doesn't conform to the styling syntax (e.g. "color: 'red'"). Yet, if I replace curly braces with double quotes, the code doesn't run.

1) Is there an ES6/JSX/React rule that converts object literals to the double quote format? (How does this work?)

2) Why wouldn't replacing the curly brackets with double quotes work? (Tried it on codepen)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style), the style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. So if you replace it with quoted string, it wouldn't work.

They choose this approach because this is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes.

Note that style name are camelCased rather than dash-separated. i.e. `marginLeft` rather than `margin-left`.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an ES6/JSX/React rule that converts object literals to the double quote format? (How does this work?)

The `style` prop either accepts a string or an object value. So in a sense, yes, the object is converted to the proper CSS text string. This is very similar to the `style` property of DOM elements.

However, this is specific behavior to the `style` prop of components representing HTML elements. If that was done to every component it wouldn't be possible to pass objects as prop values to custom components.

> Why wouldn't replacing the curly brackets with double quotes work?

Because the **string** `"{color: 'red'}"` isn't valid CSS. The fact that you tried to replace the curly braces makes me wonder whether you understand the difference.

A JSX attribute can either have the form `foo="bar"` or `foo={bar}`. In the first case, the value passed to `foo` will be a string, containing the value `bar`. In the second case, whatever is inside the braces (`{}`) is evaluated as a JavaScript expression and its result is passed to `foo`.

This might be more obvious if we look at what these JSX snippets are converted to:

```
// In:
<div style="color:red" />
// Out:
React.createElement("div", { style: "color:red" });

// In:
<div style={{color: 'red'}} />
// Out:
React.createElement('div', { style: { color: 'red' } });

// Therefore
// In:
 <div style="{color: 'red'}" />
// Out:
React.createElement("div", { style: "{color: 'red'}" });
```